# How to revoke a certificate?

Tags: networking

As a network administrator for my company, i manage a network of more than 300 machines. All the servers in the network are running on Windows Server 2003, and i have clients that run Windows 2000 Professional and Windows XP Professional.

We are using Microsoft Certification Server in enterprise CA mode for issuing and revoking certificates for all users and computers. Mike, who left the company last week, was using a digital certificate for secure email communication. I realize that his certificate would not be used any more and must be revoked.

Describe the procedure that i will follow to revoke this certificate.

Comment: This smells of homework.

Comment: At least make an effort to do your homework, please. Why not tell us what you've tried or what you don't understand?

Comment: Seems like this user has posted quite a few homework-looking questions recently. As a general rule, show us what you have tried so far. Rephrasing the question is a good start, though...

Answer (score 0):

1. Logon to the server that serves your certification authority (e.g. via RDP).
2. Start -> Administrative Tools -> Certification Authority
3. Expand the tree, select 'Issued certificates'
4. Find Mike's certificate, right click on it -> All Tasks -> Revoke Certificate